# Ubuntu 15.04 & Windows 10 Dual Boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 15.04, uefi

I've tried to install Ubuntu twice, but I can't seem to boot into it. After the install the computer automatically reboots into Windows. I've tried running repair-boot (http://paste.ubuntu.com/12364293), it told me that i need to disable to secure boot, so I did and ran it again (http://paste.ubuntu.com/12364354). No changes, computer still boots automatically into Windows. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With EFI there is no traditional boot manager loaded from the MBR that is responsible for booting every OS on the disk. Instead each OS places its bootloader in the EFI partition, which can then be selected from the EFI boot menu.

In your case the EFI partition is `/dev/sda2` and according to `boot-repair`contains the Windows bootloader as well as Grub.

How to enter the boot menu depends on the manufacturer of the firmware. I would guess there is a prompt at boot time, hinting at which key to press.

As far as I can see from `grub.cfg`, there is an entry to boot Windows 8 from Grub, by chainloading the Windows bootmanager from the EFI partition. This way you might be able to set Ubuntu as the default OS to boot in the EFI settings and still get the opportunity to boot Windows.