# Grub not showing up even after running boot-repair and disabling secure boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

Also posted here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2350231

I was able to succesfully dual boot Ubunt 16.10 with Windows 10. However, the grub menu is not showing up, even after running boot-repair and disabling fast startup and secure boot. The pastebin report from boot-repair is here: http://paste2.org/C6WbWxA5

Comment: Please edit and post hardware specs. Some notebooks require additional steps.

Comment: You seem to have an HP. Some HPs, especially older ones, have buggy EFIs that produce the symptoms you report. There are many questions and answers about this on this problem on this forum. I suggest you see [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/685122/what-should-i-do-to-get-ubuntu-dual-boot-with-windows-10-on-this-toshiba-laptop) for starters.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by going to BIOS, and switching the order of the Windows bootloader and the Ubuntu bootloader.